# SharedMemory container problems

Tags: c++, containers, shared-memory

I've created the following code for testing shared memory allocators and containers..

The allocator (basic allocator that just keeps a pointer to a memory block + the size:

```
template<typename T>
struct SharedMemoryAllocator
{
    typedef std::size_t size_type;
    typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;
    typedef T* pointer;
    typedef const T* const_pointer;
    typedef T& reference;
    typedef const T& const_reference;
    typedef T value_type;

    void* memory;
    std::size_t size;


    SharedMemoryAllocator(void* memory, std::size_t size) noexcept : memory(memory), size(size) {};
    SharedMemoryAllocator(const SharedMemoryAllocator& other) noexcept : memory(other.memory), size(other.size) {};

    template<typename U>
    SharedMemoryAllocator(const SharedMemoryAllocator<U>& other) noexcept : memory(other.memory), size(other.size) {};

    template<typename U>
    SharedMemoryAllocator& operator = (const SharedMemoryAllocator<U>& other) { return *this; }
    SharedMemoryAllocator<T>& operator = (const SharedMemoryAllocator& other) { return *this; }
    ~SharedMemoryAllocator() {}

    pointer address(reference value) const {return &value;}
    const_pointer address(const_reference value) const {return &value;}

    pointer allocate(size_type n, const void* hint = 0) {return static_cast<T*>(memory);}
    void deallocate(T* ptr, size_type n) {}

    template<typename U, typename... Args>
    void construct(U* ptr, Args&&... args) {::new(static_cast<void*>(ptr)) U(std::forward<Args>(args)...);}
    void construct(pointer ptr, const T& val) {new(static_cast<T*>(ptr)) T(val);}

    template<typename U>
    void destroy(U* ptr) {ptr->~U();}
    void destroy(pointer ptr) {ptr->~T();}

    size_type max_size() const {return size / sizeof(T);}

    template<typename U>
    struct rebind {typedef SharedMemoryAllocator<U> other;};
};

template <typename T, typename U>
inline bool operator == (const SharedMemoryAllocator<T>& a, const SharedMemoryAllocator<U>& b)
{
    return (a == b);
}

template <typename T, typename U>
inline bool operator != (const SharedMemoryAllocator<T>& a, const SharedMemoryAllocator<U>& b)
{
    return !(a == b);
}
```

The container (Just a container that allocates memory using the SharedMemory allocator):

```
template<typename T, typename allocator = std::allocator<T>>
class CVector
{
private:
    T* memory;
    std::size_t size, capacity;
    allocator alloc;

public:
    CVector() : memory(nullptr), size(0), capacity(0), alloc(allocator()) {}
    CVector(const allocator &alloc) : memory(nullptr), size(0), capacity(0), alloc(alloc) {}
    ~CVector()
    {
        if(memory)
        {
            for(std::size_t i = 0; i < this->size; ++i)
            {
                alloc.destroy(memory + i);
            }

            alloc.deallocate(memory, capacity);
            memory = nullptr;
        }
    }

    void reserve(std::size_t size)
    {
        if(capacity < size)
        {
            capacity = size;
            void* mem = alloc.allocate(capacity);

            if(memory && memory != mem)
            {
                memcpy(static_cast<char*>(mem), memory, size * sizeof(T));

                for(std::size_t i = 0; i < this->size; ++i)
                {
                    alloc.destroy(memory + i);
                }

                alloc.deallocate(memory, capacity);
                memory = nullptr;
            }

            memory = static_cast<T*>(mem);
        }
    }

    void push_back(T&& value)
    {
        if(capacity == 0)
        {
            reserve(1);
        }

        if(size >= capacity)
        {
            reserve(capacity * 2);
        }

        alloc.construct(memory + size++, value);
    }

    T& operator[](std::size_t size)
    {
        return *(memory + size);
    }

    const T& operator[](std::size_t size) const
    {
        return *(memory + size);
    }
};
```

Main:

```
int main()
{
    MemoryMap mem{"Local\\Test", 5000, std::ios::in | std::ios::out};
    mem.open();
    mem.map();

    typedef CVector<int, SharedMemoryAllocator<int>> SHMVec;


    SHMVec* vec = ::new(mem.data()) SHMVec(SharedMemoryAllocator<int>(static_cast<char*>(mem.data()) + sizeof(SHMVec), 1024 - sizeof(SHMVec)));

    vec->reserve(100);
    vec->push_back(100);
    vec->push_back(200);
    vec->push_back(300);

    std::cout<<"Address: "<<mem.data()<<"\n";
    std::cin.get();

    SHMVec* ptrVec = reinterpret_cast<SHMVec*>(mem.data());
    std::cout<<(*ptrVec)[0];


    vec->~SHMVec();
}
```

I read somewhere that std::vector cannot be placed in SharedMemory because it might do some tracking of its own in the current process's address space. So I decided to write my own "vector" which is just a cheap class.

Next, I allocate a shared memory block and I construct the container into that block as shown above in "main".

In the other program, I do (Main):

```
int main()
{
    MemoryMap mem{"Local\\Test", 5000, std::ios::in};
    mem.open();
    mem.map();

    typedef CVector<int, SharedMemoryAllocator<int>> SHMVec;

    std::cout<<"Address: "<<mem.data()<<"\n";
    SHMVec* ptrVec = reinterpret_cast<SHMVec*>(mem.data());
    std::cout<<(*ptrVec)[0];
}
```

When both programs map the shared memory block at 0x370000 it works. However, if one program allocates the SharedMemoryBlock at 0x370000 and the second at 0x380000, it crashes (the second program crashes trying to access the container created by the first).

Any ideas why this happens? The container is IN the shared memory block. Why does it matter that the address of the blocks have to be the EXACT same?

Comment: "it crashes badly" is your problem description?

Comment: Well.. It crashes with "Access Violation" if that helps. I just want to know why the shared memory block has to be allocated at the same address in BOTH processes.

Comment: No, it does not help. Load up your debugger.

Comment: How is a debugger going to help me? The container is in the shared memory. The second process can access the container perfectly fine but only if both processes map the shared memory to the exact same virtual address. A debugger won't help me figure out "why".

Comment: If you want to be able to map memory to different location, you need to use offsets instead of pointers -- containers typically use pointers, and hence cannot be mapped to different address locations.

Comment: Also, containers does not allow concurrent access -- so you will need some locking if you are doing more than just reading.

Comment: Yes, a debugger will help you figure out why. Attach the debugger to both processes (or start two debuggers) and attack it from both sides. It will also give you stack traces and the ability to step through code to make sure your variables contain the expected value.

Comment: _"How is a debugger going to help me?"_ By giving you more of a clue what your program is doing than "it crashes badly". It's _basic_ software development. How do you work without a debugger???

Comment: No need to downvote the question because actually, it _is_ quite a difficult/interesting technical problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
template<typename T, typename allocator = std::allocator<T>>
class CVector
{
private:
    T* memory;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Because in your programs the SHMVector object itself is stored in shared memory, you store its data members in shared memory. Thus the pointer to the elements (`memory` in this case) is stored in shared memory.

If the shared memory segment is loaded at a different address, then `memory` will point at an invalid address in the memory space of one of the two programs.

Maybe simple solution: don't put the SHMVec object itself in shared memory, only the elements.

Answer (score 0):

boost::interprocess can help you keeping containers in shared memory - see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/interprocess/allocators_containers.html#interprocess.allocators_containers.containers_explained.containers